# Short circuit within if statement loop

Tags: python, list, function, set

I am writing a def to evaluate user-defined numbers into a set list. the def is supposed to check the length and output to the user a printed list of the first ten. The printed statement does not appear. I think it is shortcircuting. I

```
# Function to check the length of the list
def Check_Length():
    Number_List_A =[]
    if len(Number_List_A) >10:
        Number_List_A = Number_List_A[0:10]
        print ('The first ten will only be used.', Number_List_A)
```

Comment: You only have one condition, so "short circuit" isn't possible... Please debug more and print the list first before checking the length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined an empty list and then tested if its length is greater than 10. Since an empty list has length 0, the logic under the `if` statement will never be processed.

A more useful function will take an input list as an argument:

```
def Check_Length(input_list):
    if len(input_list) > 10:
        print('The first ten will only be used.', input_list[:10])
```

For example:

```
Check_Length(list(range(20)))
# The first ten will only be used. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```